# Ezplot cosine function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to ezplot this function(f(x)= e^-2t cost  t=[-20,20]), and I guess i'm missing the syntax or something.

```
t=[-20:20]
x= e^-2*t,cos(t)
ezplot(t,x)
```

but it bringing out an error

Comment: Do you want to plot this function: (e^(-2*t)) * cos(t)?

Comment: `e` is not the Euler number, `exp(1)` is.

Comment: yes this is the function i want to plot (e^(-2*t)) * cos(t).

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing between x-y plot and function plot, plus you have several syntax errors.

First, `t` is a 41 elements vector between `-21` and `21`.

Second, unless you predefined a variable `e` then `e^(-2*t)` will give you `Undefined function or variable 'e'.` error. for exponential function just use `exp(-2*t)`.

Third, assume you fixed the syntax errors such that `x = exp(-2*t).*cos(t);`, then `x` is also a 41 elements vector, and therefore you can simply plot it using `plot(t,x)`. `ezplot` (or `fplot` in newer versions) is used for plotting *functions* (rather than vectors). If you want to plot the *function* in the `[-21,21]` interval do something like:

```
f = @(t) exp(-2*t).*cos(t); % this is a function handle
ezplot(f,[-20 20]) % use ezplot with function handle and t interval
```